# Upgrading to TFS 2013. Parameters tab is blank when queuing up a build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to migrate from TFS 2012 Update 2 to TFS 2013.
Following the documentation I installed TFS 2012.2 on the new hardware, backed up/restored the databases, then installed TFS 2013 as an upgrade.

I can see the Team Project and the builds. The problem is when I right click a build to queue up a new one and click on the Parameters tab I just get a blank panel. My best guess is there was an error loading the parameters. Note those builds worked fine in TFS 2012.2.

If I create a new build from scratch and I use their new default template (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml) I still get the same error.

I don't see any errors in the output window or the event log.

---

It turns out it's a [known bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/18/visual-studio-2013-tfs-version-control-build.aspx) with VS2013 connecting to TFS2013

---

The VS2013 [hotfix](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/C/D/6CD8507E-E11A-46DC-AE13-663ECAB66E18/VS12-KB2898341.exe) has been released. Taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5daca758-5c14-48c7-b9dc-150a011e6c03/after-upgrading-to-tfs-2013-build-parameters-are-blank-when-queuing-up-a-build?forum=tfsbuild).

Comment: What version are your build agents?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, this was fixed in Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 (see [KB 2911573](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2911573)).