# TFS Build Process Parameters aren't displaying / loading

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, build-process, tfsbuild

In my build definition, I have some parameters set to "Always Show", like this one:

[image: build definition]

When I queue a new build, the parameter(s) should display in this dialog:

[image: build dialog]

Instead, I get this error:

> Summary: There were 0 failures, 1 errors and 0 warnings loading custom activities and services.
>   Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What is causing this? I have Visual Studio 2013 and TFS Power Tools 2013 installed on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: We're running TFS 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your workflow is using some Visual Studio 2012 activity, so you have two options:

1. Install VS 2012
2. Update your workflow and any custom activity to reference 2013 assemblies

Comment: I installed Visual Studio 2012, and I no longer get any errors, but the build process parameters tab is still empty, as in the screenshot above, even though I am certain the build has exposed parameters. Any other ideas?

Comment: Found my own note http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601446/upgrading-to-tfs-2013-parameters-tab-is-blank-when-queuing-up-a-build. Need to install 2013 Update 1 or later.